# django collectstatic does not exclude external folder

Tags: python, django, collectstatic

I located my client project folder and django project folder under the root folder separately. I configured django settings.py to contain client's app folder to serve in development and dist folder to be gathered by collectstatic

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "Client/app"), # in development
                    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "Client/dist"), # to be gathered by collectstatic 
                   ]
```

`Client/app` contains original js/css/html files for development and
`Client/dist` contains concatenated and uglified files for production.

Because `Client/app` folder is only for development, I want to exclude the folder when I use collectstaic command.

However, `collectstatic -i app` does not exclude Client/app folder. I tried

```
collectstatic -i Client/app
collectstatic -i ../Client/app
collectstatic -i app*
```

but, nothing did work.

How can I exclude folder outside django directory?

Comment: http://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/django-and-static-files/ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/ http://www.leonardogentile.com/blog/using-multiple-settings-files-in-django/ refer the above and try @spectra's suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not do that normally. You would define a different `STATICFILES_DIR` depending on what environment you run.

Very basic idea:

```
if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "Client/app")]
else:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "Client/dist")]
```

Instead of relying on the `DEBUG` setting though, I'd recommend you use a separate config file for each. You then choose which to run when you invoke Django.

For instance, assuming this file tree:

```
settings/
    ├ __init__.py     # empty
    ├ dev.py
    └ prod.py
```

…you'd start Django this way:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings.dev"
./manage.py runserver
```

To avoid repeating shared configuration, create a `common.py` and import it from both `dev.py` and `prod.py`, using `from settings.common import *` (probably the only use case where it's permissible to import *).

Though it does not technically answer your question, I think this is a cleaner approach to the wider problem of handling environment-specific configuration.

Comment: I agree splitting settings makes more sense. Thanks